# How to find the inverse of only the last-row block of the block matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, block-matrices

[This image contains the specific patterned block matrix which has,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6SXi.png)

1. The diagonal matrices A<sub>11</sub> .... A<sub>33</sub> are square matrices are of size m x m.
2. The matrices in the last row-block Â<sub>11</sub><sup>T</sup> .... Â<sub>33</sub><sup>T</sup>
   is of size n x m where n < m
3. The matrices in the last column-block Â<sub>11</sub>.... Â<sub>33</sub> is of size m x n where n < m. Therefore, the last row and last column block matrices are rectangular matrices.
4. The last row block  Â<sub>11</sub><sup>T</sup> .... Â<sub>33</sub><sup>T</sup> is the transpose of last column  block Â<sub>11</sub>.... Â<sub>33</sub> of the block-matrix.
5. The end matrix Â
   <sub>k</sub> of the block-matrix is of size n x n.

[The corresponding example is explained with specific values for m and n here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/466827-inverse-of-a-specific-pattern-of-block-matrix-with-last-row-and-column?s_tid=prof_contriblnk#question_466827) (In this link, same question is being posted in mathworks but there are no answers to that.)

**I have two questions :**

1) Is there any specific name for this pattern of block-matrix ?

2) Is there any way to find the inverse of just the last-row block ( Â<sub>11</sub><sup>T</sup> .... Â<sub>33</sub><sup>T</sup> Â<sub>k</sub>) of the block matrix without finding the inverse of the entire block matrix?

(Additionally I have also attached this image for pattern of block matrix)

[Pattern of the block matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNahn.png)

Comment: I'd call it a block-arrowhead matrix, seeing as an [arrowhead matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix) is already a term. What exactly do you mean by inverting the last row-block since that isn't a square matrix? Also, are the blocks on the diagonal symmetric, or just square?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inverting the last row-block since that isn't a square matrix?  Meaning: I meant after taking the inverse of the entire block-matrix, I want just the last-row block of the inverted matrix for my computations. So, i mentioned I need just the last-row block output of the inverted matrix without actually finding the entire block matrix inverse.

Comment: Also, are the blocks on the diagonal symmetric, or just square? Reply: Just Square

Comment: Ahh, so you meant "the last row-block of the inverse" as opposed to "the inverse of the last row-block". Note that these mean two different things. Anyway, you can still use my answer below, except only perform steps 1-5.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yes, "the last row-block of the inverse"  and "the inverse of the last row-block" means different, when I look now. Apologies, I hadn't noticed this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a block-arrowhead matrix, seeing as an [arrowhead matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix) is already a term.

I don't know what you mean by inverting the last row-block since that isn't square, but we can efficiently compute the inverse of the entire matrix using the [block matrix inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\
    \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
     \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
      -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1} \\
    -\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
       \left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}$$

For convenience, let's notate the blocks of the matrix as follows: $$\begin{bmatrix}A_1& & & &B_1\\  &A_2& & &B_2\\  & &\ddots& &\vdots\\  & & &A_k&B_k\\ C_1&C_2&\cdots&C_k&D \end{bmatrix}$$ where $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ are square $n \times n$ matrices, $B_1,\ldots,B_k$ are $n \times m$ matrices, $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ are $m \times n$ matrices, and $D$ is an $m \times m$ matrix.

Then, we can apply the above block matrix inversion formula with $\mathbf{A} = \text{blockdiag}(A_1,\ldots,A_k)$ (i.e. the block-diagonal portion of the matrix), $\mathbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix}B_1^T & B_2^T & \cdots & B_k^T\end{bmatrix}^T$, $\mathbf{C} = \begin{bmatrix}C_1 & C_2 & \cdots & C_k\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{D} = D$.

Then we can compute the inverse of the whole matrix in the following steps:

1. Compute $\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \text{blockdiag}(A_1^{-1},\ldots,A_k^{-1})$
2. Compute $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}C_1A_1^{-1} & \cdots & C_kA_k^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$
3. Compute $\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B} = D - (\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1})\mathbf{B}$
4. Compute $\mathbf{S}:= (\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}$
5. Compute $-(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1} = -\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1})$
6. Compute $-\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{S} = \begin{bmatrix}-A_1^{-1}B_1\mathbf{S}\\ \vdots \\ -A_k^{-1}B_k\mathbf{S} \end{bmatrix}$
7. Compute $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} = (\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{S})(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1})$
8. Compute $\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1}$

Step 1 involves inverting $k$ matrices of size $n \times n$, which takes $O(kn^{\omega})$ operations. (Here $\omega$ is the exponent in the runtime of the [matrix inversion algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) you are using. Gaussian elimination has $\omega = 3$, Strassen's has $\omega = \log_2 7 \approx 2.807$, and other less practical algorithms have smaller values of $\omega$.)

Step 2 involves $k$ multiplications of an $m \times n$ matrix and an $n \times n$ matrix, which takes $O(kmn^2)$ operations.

Step 3 involves multiplying a $m \times kn$ matrix with an $kn \times m$ matrix and subtracting it from an $m \times m$ matrix, which takes $O(km^2n)+O(m^2) = O(km^2n)$ operations.

Step 4 involves inverting an $m \times m$ matrix which takes $O(m^{\omega})$ operations.

Step 5 involves multiplying an $m \times m$ matrix with an $m \times kn$ matrix, which takes $O(km^2n)$ operations.

Step 6 involves $k$ products of an $n \times n$ matrix with an $n \times m$ matrix with an $m \times m$ matrix, which takes $O(kmn^2+km^2n)$ operations.

Step 7 involves multiplying an $kn \times m$ matrix with an $m \times kn$ matrix, which takes $O(k^2mn^2)$ operations.

Step 8 involves adding a matrix with at most $kn^2$ entries to the previous result, which takes $O(kn^2)$ operations.

If we use Gaussian elimination to do all the inversions, and $n \gg m,k$, then the dominant part of the cost is the matrix inversion steps. This block-arrowhead inversion algorithm will take $O(kn^3)$ operations while Gaussian elimination with an arbitrary $(kn+m) \times (kn+m)$ matrix will take $O(k^3n^3)$ operations. Analyzing the cost savings in other cases is a bit tricky, but the above algorithm usually saves work over a general inversion algorithm.